# React Native: Load value from AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

**How can i load data from AsyncStorage to redux store at the time of application's first page loading?**

I tried to call a check function in `componentWillMount`.

```
componentWillMount(){
    debugger;
    this.check();
}
```

and in check i tried to take the value from `AsyncStorage` and store it to redux store object.

```
async check(){
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('location').then((location) => {
        this.props.location[0].city = location;
      }
  });
  this.props.selectLocation(this.props.location);
}
```

As it is a Asynchronous function , I am unable to get the values and store it view `selectLocation` action of redux.

**How to properly get the data and store it before component gets mounted ?**

**Update:**

In my index.android.js i changed my store like this,

```
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'
import combineReducers from './src/Redux/reducers/combineReducers';
// const store = createStore(combineReducers);
const store = compose(autoRehydrate())(createStore)(combineReducers)
persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, () => {
  console.log('restored');
  console.log(store);
})


export default class ReactNavigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: await this.check();

Answer (score 0):

Your component should listen to store through event listeners for changes and should show the data when the data is loaded into the store.

For the time being when the data is not there, you should show something like a spinner to let the user know that it's loading.

Ideally, you don't want to make componentWillMount wait for the data to be loaded.